D2D DEBUG ERROR - An operation failed because a device-dependent resource is associated with the wrong ID2D1Device (resource domain)
I want to extract the binary data from a bitmap, but I encounter an error when drawing the bitmap into the ID2D1RenderTarget. I'm not very familiar with DirectX resource management. The _D2dDeviceContext5 is indeed indirectly created by _D2dFactory6. I don't quite understand.
#include <Windows.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include <dxgi1_5.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3d11_4.h>
#include <d2d1.h>
#include <d2d1_3.h>
#include <d2d1_3helper.h>
#include <wincodec.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dcompiler")
#pragma comment (lib, "D2d1")
#pragma comment (lib, "dxguid")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d11")
#pragma comment (lib, "dxgi")


int WINAPI wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPWSTR pszCmdLine, _In_ int iCmdShow)
{
    CComPtr<ID2D1Device5> _D2dDevice5;
    CComPtr<ID2D1Factory> _D2dFactory;
    CComPtr<ID2D1Factory6> _D2dFactory6;
    CComPtr<ID2D1DeviceContext5> _D2dDeviceContext5;

    CComPtr<ID3D11Device> _D3dDevice;
    CComPtr<ID3D11Device5> _D3dDevice5;
    CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> _D3dDeviceContext;
    CComPtr<IDXGIDevice4> _D3d_DXGI_D2d_;

    CComPtr<IWICImagingFactory2> _IWICFactory2;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevelSupported;

    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED | COINIT_SPEED_OVER_MEMORY);

    D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG | D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT, NULL, 0, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &_D3dDevice, &featureLevelSupported, &_D3dDeviceContext);
    _D3dDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Device5), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&_D3dDevice5));

    //D2dFactory
    D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS const d2dDeviceoptions = { D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_INFORMATION };
    D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_MULTI_THREADED, d2dDeviceoptions, &_D2dFactory);
    _D2dFactory->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID2D1Factory6), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&_D2dFactory6));

    //D2dDevice
    _D3dDevice5->QueryInterface(&_D3d_DXGI_D2d_);
    _D2dFactory6->CreateDevice(_D3d_DXGI_D2d_, &_D2dDevice5);

    //D2dDeviceContext
    _D2dDevice5->CreateDeviceContext(D2D1_DEVICE_CONTEXT_OPTIONS_ENABLE_MULTITHREADED_OPTIMIZATIONS, &_D2dDeviceContext5);

    //IWICFactory
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory2, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&_IWICFactory2));



    //
    LPCWSTR pngPath = _T("C:\\Img1.png");
    //

    CComPtr<IWICStream> stream;
    _IWICFactory2->CreateStream(&stream);
    stream->InitializeFromFilename(pngPath, GENERIC_READ);

    CComPtr<IWICBitmapDecoder> decoder;
    _IWICFactory2->CreateDecoderFromStream(stream, NULL, WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad, &decoder);

    CComPtr<IWICBitmapFrameDecode> frameDecode;
    decoder->GetFrame(0, &frameDecode);

    CComPtr<IWICFormatConverter> converter;
    _IWICFactory2->CreateFormatConverter(&converter);
    converter->Initialize(
        frameDecode, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA, WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, NULL, 0, WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom
    );

    CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> bitmap;
    _D2dDeviceContext5->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(converter, NULL, &bitmap);


    // CopyBitmapToCPU
    char** data = nullptr;
    size_t dataSize = 0;
    D2D1_SIZE_U bitmapSize = bitmap->GetPixelSize();

    CComPtr<IWICBitmap> wicBitmap;
    _IWICFactory2->CreateBitmap(bitmapSize.width, bitmapSize.height, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA, WICBitmapCacheOnLoad, &wicBitmap);
    CComPtr<ID2D1RenderTarget> target;
    _D2dFactory6->CreateWicBitmapRenderTarget(wicBitmap, D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(), &target);

    target->BeginDraw();
    target->DrawBitmap(bitmap); // D2D DEBUG ERROR - An operation failed because a device-dependent resource is associated with the wrong ID2D1Device (resource domain).
    target->EndDraw();

    WICRect rcLock = { 0,0,static_cast<INT>(bitmapSize.width), static_cast<INT>(bitmapSize.height) };
    CComPtr<IWICBitmapLock> lock;
    wicBitmap->Lock(&rcLock, WICBitmapLockRead, &lock);

    UINT bufferSize = 0;
    unsigned char* tempTargetData = nullptr;
    lock->GetDataPointer(&bufferSize, &tempTargetData);
    if (tempTargetData != NULL) {
        *data = new char[bufferSize];
        memcpy(data, tempTargetData, bufferSize);
        dataSize = static_cast<size_t>(bufferSize);
    }
    return 0;
}

I don't know where to start trying. I'm afraid that changing the creation order might cause other factories to fail.

Your WIC objects are using a different device than _D2dDevice5. You want these to be the same device. You need to use an interface that accepts ID2D1Device for WIC resource creation
HRESULT CreateImageEncoder(   [in]  ID2D1Device      *pD2DDevice,   [out] IWICImageEncoder **ppWICImageEncoder );

You could also copy a resource from one device to another, but you would only do that as a last resort

Also Windows.Graphics.Imaging will be a better API if you can get it to do what you want

You don't need Direct2D not DirectX to "extract the binary data from a bitmap". What exactly are you trying to do? What is a "bitmap" in this context? A WIC bitmap? a D2D bitmap?
